# Micronaut consumes and produces stopped working after upgrade to micronaut 4

Tags: java, kotlin, microservices, micronaut, micronaut-rest

On micronaut version 3, it worked fine, while migrating to micronaut 4, stopped working

In a endpoint annotated with

```
 @Get("/{someId}/someAction", produces = ["application/some.v1+json"] )
```

When I call it (eg. postman) micronaut gives me an error on console

`io.micronaut.http.codec.CodecException: Cannot encode value [[]]. No possible encoders found for media type: application/vnd.v1+json`

here's a piece of my controller

```kotlin
@Validated
@Controller("/something")
class SomethingController(@Inject val service: SomeService) {

    @Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
    @Get("/{someId}/someAction", 
         produces = ["application/some.v1+json"], 
         consumes = ["application/some.v1+json"])
    fun getSomething(
            someId: UUID,
            principal: Principal
    ): List<SomeResource>  {
        principal as MyIdentity
        return service.findAll(someId, principal)
    }
```

My service has more endpoints, is there a way to write one codec that handle with all those customs produces and consumes?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a codec on application yaml, I was able to fix my issue. I wondering if there is another way to fix that, since micronaut 3 supported that

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#consumesAnnotation